# Bit-8 in an X11 event

Tags: events, x11, xcb

I am trying to understand X11, and I am currently working with XCB.  I often get an event_ response of 150 where I would expect 22. 150 is of course 128+22. So far these are generated from windows which are children of the window manager, as far as I am concerned. In all the documentation I have studied I can find no inkling of what this may signify, although I suspect it may be a reminder of an unacknowledged event.Can anyone enlighten me.

I am just seeking technical info.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any good link with an answer right now (but I suspect that there are already questions on SO for this).

The highest bit indicates whether the event was generated by the X11 server (bit unset) or by some other client via a `SendEvent` request (bit set).

So, if the window manager sends e.g. an UnmapNotify event to your window, it will have event code 18+128. If your window really is unmapped, you get an event with event code 18.

Comment: In the protocol specification, it's defined at https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#event_format -- "Every event contains an 8-bit type code. The most significant bit in this code is set if the event was generated from a SendEvent request."