# Drawing an image using xcb

Tags: c++, linux, x11, xlib, xcb

I am trying to make an X11 window dump the content of a buffer using `xcb`.The code should fill the window with a white background, and a filled circle. Similar code works with XLib - so I am confident with the basic drawing. My problem is with the blitting to screen.

Basically:

- I create a H*W buffer (which I paint white).
- I call `xcb_image_create_native()` with that buffer.
- Then I create a pixmap, dump the native image to it - and then draw the pixmap on window.
- Dumping the image into the window will also fail (both pixmaps and windows are drawable in XLib, so it should work anyway).

I am missing something trivial - which I cannot understand.

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_image.h>

constexpr auto size_width = 640;
constexpr auto size_height = 480;

int32_t buf[size_height*size_height];

auto put_pixel(int x, int y, uint32_t color) -> void {
    buf[(y * size_width) + x] = color;
}

auto fill_circle(int x, int y, int r, uint32_t c) -> void {
    for (int dy = -r; dy < r; dy++) {
        for (int dx = -r; dx < r; dx++) {
            if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= r * r)
                put_pixel(x + dx, y + dy, c);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    xcb_connection_t *connection;
    xcb_screen_t *screen;
    xcb_gcontext_t graphics_context;
    xcb_window_t window_xcb;
    xcb_image_t* xcb_image;
    auto format = XCB_IMAGE_FORMAT_Z_PIXMAP;
    uint8_t depth;
    uint32_t mask = XCB_CW_BACK_PIXEL | XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK;
    uint32_t values[2];

    connection = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
    assert(connection);
    screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(connection)).data;
    depth = screen->root_depth;
    values[0] = screen->black_pixel;
    values[1] = XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS;

    window_xcb = xcb_generate_id(connection);
    xcb_create_window(connection, XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT, window_xcb, screen->root, 0, 0, size_width,
                      size_height, 10, XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT, screen->root_visual, mask, values);
    xcb_map_window(connection, window_xcb);


    graphics_context = xcb_generate_id(connection);
    xcb_create_gc(connection, graphics_context, window_xcb, mask, values);
    xcb_image =
        xcb_image_create_native(connection, size_width, size_height,
                                format, depth, (uint8_t *)buf,
                                size_width * size_height * 4,
                                (uint8_t *)buf);


    xcb_flush(connection);
    memset(buf, size_width*size_height*4, 0xff);
    fill_circle(100, 100, 20, 0xff0000);

    {
        xcb_generic_event_t *event;

        while (true) {
            event = xcb_wait_for_event(connection);
            if (event == nullptr) {
                continue;
            }

            switch (event->response_type) {
            case XCB_EXPOSE: {
                xcb_expose_event_t *ev = (xcb_expose_event_t *)event;

                auto depth = screen->root_depth;
                xcb_pixmap_t pixmap = xcb_generate_id(connection);
                xcb_create_pixmap(connection, depth, pixmap, ev->window,
                                  size_width, size_height);
                xcb_image_put(connection, pixmap, graphics_context, xcb_image, 0, 0, 0);
                xcb_copy_area(connection, pixmap, window_xcb, graphics_context, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        size_width, size_height);
                xcb_flush(connection);
            } break;
            case XCB_DESTROY_NOTIFY:
                break;
            default:
                //            xcb_free_event(event);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the program under `xtrace` and saw that its CreateGC request was failing with a BadPixmap error:

```
000:<:0003: 16: Request(55): CreateGC cid=0x03a00001 drawable=0x03a00000 values={}
000:>:0003:Error 4=Pixmap: major=55, minor=0, bad=0x00000000, seq=0003
```

The code was passing the same values to CreateGC as for CreateWindow.

Also, the error handling is weird. The code goes into an endless loop if the X11 connection breaks. I fixed that by making the program exit instead.

Now, why does the connection break? Maximum request size!

```c
printf("Maximum request size is 4 * %d bytes while we will be trying to send 4 * %d bytes of data (plus request overhead)\n",
    xcb_get_maximum_request_length(connection), size_width * size_height);
```

Output says that the program is sending too much data:

```
Maximum request size is 4 * 4194303 bytes while we will be trying to send 4 * 307200 bytes of data (plus request overhead)
```

I shrank the image size to 100 x 100. Now I get a red circle.

Splitting the PutImage request into smaller parts is left as an exercise to the reader.

In total, I did these changes:

```
--- t.c.orig    2023-05-06 14:22:14.160130873 +0200
+++ t.c 2023-05-06 14:33:04.777321692 +0200
@@ -1,11 +1,12 @@
 #include <cassert>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <cstdint>
+#include <cstdio>
 #include <xcb/xcb.h>
 #include <xcb/xcb_image.h>
 
-constexpr auto size_width = 640;
-constexpr auto size_height = 480;
+constexpr auto size_width = 100;
+constexpr auto size_height = 100;
 
 int32_t buf[size_height*size_height];
 
@@ -48,17 +49,19 @@ int main()
 
 
     graphics_context = xcb_generate_id(connection);
-    xcb_create_gc(connection, graphics_context, window_xcb, mask, values);
+    xcb_create_gc(connection, graphics_context, window_xcb, 0, nullptr);
     xcb_image =
         xcb_image_create_native(connection, size_width, size_height,
                                 format, depth, (uint8_t *)buf,
                                 size_width * size_height * 4,
                                 (uint8_t *)buf);
 
+    printf("Maximum request size is 4 * %d bytes while we will be trying to send 4 * %d bytes of data (plus request overhead)\n", xcb_get_maximum_request_length(connection), size_width * size_height);
+
 
     xcb_flush(connection);
     memset(buf, size_width*size_height*4, 0xff);
-    fill_circle(100, 100, 20, 0xff0000);
+    fill_circle(50, 50, 20, 0xff0000);
 
     {
         xcb_generic_event_t *event;
@@ -66,10 +69,12 @@ int main()
         while (true) {
             event = xcb_wait_for_event(connection);
             if (event == nullptr) {
-                continue;
+                printf("Connection broke with status %d\n", xcb_connection_has_error(connection));
+                break;
             }
+            printf("Got event of type %d\n", event->response_type);
 
-            switch (event->response_type) {
+            switch (event->response_type & 0x7f) {
             case XCB_EXPOSE: {
                 xcb_expose_event_t *ev = (xcb_expose_event_t *)event;
```

Some hint / example on how to split up a too large PutImage request: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/cairo/cairo/-/blob/8d6586f49f1c977318af7f7f9e4f24221c9122fc/src/cairo-xcb-connection-core.c#L104-144

Comment: Great! thanks! Why are you masking out the MSB of the event? Also, when I wrote this code using good old XLib - I did not have to split the painting..  I assume this was due to XLib splitting this into several `xcb_image_put()` like cairo does?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76075759/bit-8-in-an-x11-event/76085900 or https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#event_format for the MSB of the event.

Comment: Yup, you are right that XLib internally splits things up. Here is the code that computes the right size for this. Don't ask me what is special about 64 KiB here. https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libx11/-/blob/208d550954c7266fa8093b02a2a97047e1478c00/src/PutImage.c#L884-886